# minionint option not working correctly with MinionPro package set up via FontPro

Tags: fonts, symbols, minionpro

The minion integral that is used upon specifying `minionint` as an option for `MinionPro` is not displaying correctly. I installed my minion pro font as suggested by the instructions in the [FontPro](https://github.com/sebschub/FontPro) github page. Here's my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[minionint]{MinionPro}

\begin{document}

$\left\langle f\left(x\right),g\left(x\right)\right\rangle =\int_{0}^{1}f\left(t\right)g\left(t\right)dt$

\end{document}
```

Here's what I see:
[image]

I'm not sure what went wrong. I recently did a clean install of osx 10.9 on my system and installed the mactex 2013 distribution. My minion pro font came from Adobe Font Folio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the entire tex distribution and starting from scratch again fixed the problem. I believe something may have interrupted the `makeall` script provided by `FontPro`, so if you're installing MinionPro via the scripts provided in `FontPro`, make sure nothing interrupts them while being run. Aside from that, installation of Minion Pro works as suggested by the documentation.